# Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.MVC.App_Start.GlassMapperSc, Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I am new to sitecore using sitecore8.0 and mvc 5.1.0

I installed Glass.Mapper.Sc through nuget after publishing to sitecore my mvc project getting error like this please help me on this

> Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.MVC.App_Start.GlassMapperSc,
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).

Comment: What version of `Glass.Mapper.Sc` did you get from nuget?

Comment: I installed Glass.Mapper.Sc 4.1.2.67 version